# Google chart age pyramid label aligning issue

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

Colleagues, I have a problem with aligning the label using Google bar chart.

[image]

I want to label the text/figure on the extreme left position for the Female (like the figure for the Male). Can anyone assist on this?

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(chart);

    function chart()
    {
        //var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        var dataArray = [
            ['Age', 'Male', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Female', {role: 'annotation'}],
            ['0-4 years', 11, 11, -6, 6],['5-11 years', 12, 12, -13, 13],['12-17 years', 15, 15, -4, 4],['18-59 years', 11, 11, -20, 20],['60+ years', 6, 6, -3, 3]            ];

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('age_pyramid_cw'));

        var options = {
            title: '',
            titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 16, align: 'center', bold: true},
            colors: ['#FFCCCC', '#DC3912'],
            chartArea: { backgroundColor: 'white', height: '70%', top: '10%' },
            isStacked: true,
            legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 3 },
            hAxis: {
                textPosition: 'none',
                format: ';',
                title: ''
            },
            vAxis: {
                direction: 1,
                title: ''
            }
        }; 

        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
            pattern: ';'
        });

        formatter.format(data, 2)

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

</script>
<div id="age_pyramid_cw" style="width: 95%; height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can control that with the API :( Maybe you can submit a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list)?